# Why isn't this style value changing as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a system in a website I'm making that uses a single HTML file, with the user clicking buttons on either side of the page to scroll the content. Of course, I want to hide the buttons when the user reaches either end of the content (i.e. disable the left arrow when on the leftmost page). I'm using `console.log()` to print the `left` value of the `<div>` containing the content, which is what I `.animate()` with jQuery to create the effect. However, when I scroll once using the buttons, the value changes to `0px`, which is already the default CSS value of the `<div>`. Scrolling again, the value changes to `-99.9999px`, which is also the value when I scroll back to the first page. This means that my button disappears as soon as I scroll to the third page, hampering further navigation. The inline `style` attribute always contains the expected value, however. What is the reason for these discrepancies?

Be forewarned, the Snippet is *very* messed up. You might need to copy and paste into some local files. Sorry about that. The `#box` is the `<div>` you should paying attention to. Thanks!

Snippet:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("images/pinecones.JPG");
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

::selection {
  background-color: green;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background-color: green;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Cambria', sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

div.page:hover {
  font-size: 120%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#box {
  position: relative;
  left: 0%;
}

.banner-text {
  text-indent: 0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.banner-text:hover {
  font-size: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .banner-text {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .banner-text {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

/* I'll need to add more progressions of this, sizing down the margin and eventually getting rid of this to go mobile. */

#banner {
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
}

#banner-text {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 340px;
}

#navbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 340px;
  top: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.nav-text {
  text-indent: 0px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-style: italic;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-text:hover {
  font-size: 120%;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#media-box {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}

.media {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.contact-info {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.phone {
  cursor: default;
  top: 50px;
}

.email {
  top: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: block;
}

.page {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: white;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

#title {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: sans-serif; /* Redundant if decide to use sans-serif elsewhere */
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#title-text:hover {
  font-size: 100%;
}

.arrow {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
}

.left {
  left: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.right {
  right: 0px;
}

.main {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}

.intro { /* Need to fix this thing not scrolling right */
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#left {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 68px;
  width: 25%;
  height: 355px;
  right: 0px;
}

#bottom {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

/* The pages position values below */

.second {
  position: absolute;
  left: 62.5%;
}

.third {
  position: absolute;
  left: 112.5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css"/>
    <link href="simple-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bud, Branch & Blossom Landscaping, LLC</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://buzinas.github.io/simple-scrollbar/simple-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="media-box">
      <a href="#"><img id="linkedin" class="media" src="images/linkedin.png" title="Linkedin"/></a>
      <a href="#"><img id="houzz" class="media" src="images/houzz.png" title="Houzz"/></a>
      <a href="#"><img id="instagram" class="media" src="images/instagram.png" title="Instagram"/></a>
      <a href ="#"><img id="facebook" class="media" src="images/facebook.png" title="Facebook"/></a>
      <a class="contact-info phone" href="tel:+15175151723">(517)-515-1723</a>
      <a class="contact-info email" href="#">Contact us today!</a>
    </div>
    <div id="banner">
      <div id="banner-text">
        <p id="maintenance" class="banner-text">MAINTENANCE.</p>
        <p id="installation" class="banner-text">INSTALLATION.</p>
        <p id="design" class="banner-text">DESIGN.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar">
        <p id="about" class="nav-text">About Us</p>
        <p id="gallery" class="nav-text">Our Work</p> <!-- Whichever one Tommy likes better. -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Everything on top of the banner -->
    <div id="logo"><img src="images/whitelogo.png"/></div>
    <!-- Content -->
    <div id="box">
      <div class="first box">
        <img class="left arrow" src="images/left_arrow.png"/>
        <img class="right arrow" src="images/right_arrow.png"/>
        <div class="first page intro">
          <p>Bud, Branch & Blossom Landscaping is a small, independent landscaping firm that serves the Greater Lansing area.</p>
          <p>We perform a variety of landscaping services, including landscape design, plant installation and removal, hardscaping, and lawn maintenance.</p>
          <p>Bud, Branch & Blossom is also an active member of the Michigan Nursery and Landscape Association (MNLA), and is approved by the Michigan Department of Agriculture and Natural Resources (MDANR).</p>
        </div>
        <div class="first page intro">
          <p>Tommy we need another testimonial yo.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Second page -->
      <div class="second box">
        <div id="title" class="second page">
          <p id="title-text">About Us</p>
        </div>
        <div class="second page main" ss-container>
          <p>Bud, Branch & Blossom owner Tommy Morgan has spent years researching plants, shrubs, and trees. Before forming the company, he redesigned spaces in his own yard, honing his understanding of how textures and colors fit beside each other in garden beds. That appreciation for landscape composition serves his customers well. He enjoys making connections with his clients and getting to spend time outdoors doing what he loves.</p>
          <p>The business started with a few small design projects, supplemented by several lawn mowing jobs. A year after forming the company, Tommy hired his first employees – people who, as he says, “understand that all of the work we do is in service to our customers.”  He’s invested in top-of-the-line equipment, with brands like Exmark, Stihl, and Redmax lining our equipment racks.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Third page -->
      <div class="third box">
        <div id="left" class="third page" ss-container>
          <p>Design work allows us to share our creativity with our customers. Owner Tommy Morgan enjoys creating artwork with natural components. When designing a garden, many important factors must be considered, such as light, soil conditions, water, drainage conditions, and location. </p>
          <p>The first step of the design process involves a free initial consultation. This allows us to understand your needs, and gives us an opportunity to see and understand the space. Following this, a design will be presented to you, along with pictures of plants/materials being used, and an estimate of the cost.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="page">Copyright &copy; Bud, Branch & Blossom Landscaping, LLC. All rights reserved.</footer>
    <script type="text/javascript"> // Hover effects

    // Elements

    var fb = document.getElementById('facebook');
    var ig = document.getElementById('instagram');
    var hz = document.getElementById('houzz');
    var li = document.getElementById('linkedin');

    // Social media

      fb.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        fb.src = "images/facebook_hover.png";
      });

      fb.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
        fb.src = "images/facebook.png";
      });

      ig.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        ig.src = "images/instagram_hover.png";
      });

      ig.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
        ig.src = "images/instagram.png";
      });

      hz.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        hz.src = "images/houzz_hover.png";
      });

      hz.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
        hz.src = "images/houzz.png";
      });

      li.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        li.src = "images/linkedin_hover.png";
      });

      li.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
        li.src = "images/linkedin.png";
      });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> // PAGE SCRIPT
    function test() {
      xleft = document.getElementById('box').style.left;
      console.log(xleft);

      if(xleft == '-500%') {
        $('.right').css('visibility', 'hidden');
      } else {
        $('.right').css('visibility', 'visible');
      }
    }

      $('.right').click(function() {
        $('#box').animate({
          left: '-=100%'
        }, 400);

        $('.left').css('visibility', 'visible');
        test();
      });

      $('.left').click(function() {
        $('#box').animate({
          left: '+=100%'
        }, 400);

        if(xleft == '-200%') {
          $('.left').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        } else {
          $('.left').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
      });

      $('#about').click(function() {
        $('#box').animate({
          left: '-100%'
        }, 400);

        $('.left').css('visibility', 'visible');
        test();
      });

      $('#design').click(function() {
        $('#box').animate({
          left: '-200%'
        }, 400);

        $('.left').css('visibility', 'visible');
        test();
      });

      $('#installation').click(function() {
        $('#box').animate({
          left: '-300%'
        }, 400);

        $('.left').css('visibility', 'visible');
        test();
      });

      $('#maintenance').click(function() {
        $('#box').animate({
          left: '-400%'
        }, 400);

        $('.left').css('visibility', 'visible');
        test();
      });

      $('#gallery').click(function() {
        $('#box').animate({
          left: '-500%'
        }, 400);

        $('.left').css('visibility', 'visible');
        test();
      });

      $('.email').click(function() {
        $('#box').animate({
          left: '-600%'
        }, 400);

        $('.left').css('visibility', 'visible');
        test();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, to start with your HTML is invalid. `span` elements should not contain paragraphs...I'd run your code through a validator first.

Comment: Created a Fiddle for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/5o23qjjy/

Comment: I changed the `<span>`s to `<div>`s.